# Extract some information from a set into using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to implement a select interface.

You will have to choose a site, and then will appear the country where is available the site.

For this, I have a set of sites where are some informations like their name and the countries associated.

You choose the site in the "select" tag, the choice is contained in the

```
vm.selectedRequest = {};
```

then I want to display the countries associated to the site with "ng-repeat", but I got nothing.

Could you tell me what you think about this ?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cfgqst1w/) (the selector works at my home but it seems jsfiddle does not like my set.  )

Comment: @Anand the new recommended use of controlers is using this and not $scope and in your HTML ng-controller="myCtrl as xxx". cf : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the right ng-repeat you should use :

```
 <h4 ng-repeat="country in sel.selectedRequest.site.countries">{{country.name}}</h4>
```

See it working in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wBW0yjoFPtaWAXpQOqWU?p=preview)

Let just detail a bit what it mean :

```
ng-repeat="country in sel.selectedRequest.site.countries"
```

"I want to repeat the html element for each element in `sel.selectedRequest.site.countries`, in each case we will refer to a single element as `country`"

Then with `{{country.name}}` you can show the name of the current contextual country.

Comment: I edited, the link was referring to an other plunker